# Why is my Java program only reading one line of input?

Tags: java

this is probably a really simple question, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. I just started teaching myself Java using this: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/

For reference, this program relies on an input/output class from that textbook called "TextIO". You can find the code for it here: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/TextIO.java.

I made a super simple blackjack program, and I decided to try to keep track of high scores: both for # of games won, and total amount of money. The program is supposed to read scores from a text file, and then re-write the info in that text file when the user gets a higher score.

Anyway, everything seems to work fine, except that I want you to be able to enter your name for winning either most games or most money. I super-simplified it so that it just asks your name twice to try to see what the problem was (rather than only asking if you actually get a high score), and the thing is that it prints the question "enter your name" both times, but only reads input once, and the weird thing is that it only reads the input for the first one!  Here's the code:

```
/* This program allows the user to play a game of 
enter code here`* blackjack against the computer. The user can bet money
* the game will keep track of total winnings as well as
* the number of games won.
*/
public class BlackjackGame {

    //keep track of highest scoring players so far
    static String nameForGames; //name of person who won most games
    static String nameForWinnings;  //name of person who won most money
    static int maxGames;        //highest # of games won
    static int maxWinnings;     //highest amount of money earned


    static int gamesWon = 0;    //keeps track of total games won by user
    static int money = 100;     //total pot of money available for betting
    private static Deck deck = new Deck();  
    static boolean wantToPlay;  //answers whether the user wants to keep playing

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //load the high score data from the scores.txt file
            TextIO.readFile("scores.txt");
    nameForGames = TextIO.getlnString();
    maxGames = TextIO.getlnInt();
    nameForWinnings = TextIO.getlnString();
    maxWinnings = TextIO.getlnInt();

        TextIO.putln(nameForGames + " " + maxGames + " " + nameForWinnings + " " + maxWinnings);

    TextIO.readStandardInput();

    introduction();

    TextIO.put("Would you like to play");
    wantToPlay = TextIO.getBoolean();

    //user can keep playing indefinitely until they decide to stop
    while (wantToPlay == true) {
        playGame();
        if (wantToPlay == false) {
            break;
        }
        TextIO.put("Play again?");
        wantToPlay = TextIO.getBoolean();
    }

    //print results of gameplay
    TextIO.putln("\nThanks for playing!");
    TextIO.putln("You won " + gamesWon + " games and walk away with $" + money + ".");
    TextIO.putln();

//THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESNT MAKE SENSE? WHY IS IT ONLY READING INPUT ONCE?       
    TextIO.put("Enter your name: ");
    nameForWinnings = TextIO.getln();

    TextIO.putln();

    TextIO.put("Enter your name: ");
    nameForGames = TextIO.getln();

//Save new high scores to scores.txt.
    TextIO.writeFile("scores.txt");
    TextIO.putln(nameForGames);
    TextIO.putln(maxGames);
    TextIO.putln(nameForWinnings);
    TextIO.putln(maxWinnings);

    //Re-read the data from the file, and display to the player.
    System.out.println("The high scores are:");
    TextIO.readFile("scores.txt");
    nameForGames = TextIO.getlnString();
    maxGames = TextIO.getlnInt();
    nameForWinnings = TextIO.getlnString();
    maxWinnings = TextIO.getlnInt();

    TextIO.writeStandardOutput();
    TextIO.putln(nameForGames + " won " + maxGames + " games!");
    TextIO.putln(nameForWinnings + " won $" + maxWinnings + " total cash!");

} //end main()
```

Comment: Are you saying that `nameForWinnings` and  `nameForGames` print the same value when you print them? even though you've entered in different names?

Comment: In your code you have this "//THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESNT MAKE SENSE? WHY IS IT ONLY READING INPUT ONCE?   " I tested that part, and it reads the 2 inputs.

Comment: Instead of reading it twice from user the same thing, you can copy nameForWinnings to nameForGames. Sorry I am not answering the exact question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the  `getBoolean` method that you call before reading the user's name does not remove line separator characters from the stream. This means that the first call to `readln` will return what ever is left of the line, even if it's an empty string. Looking at the methods that are available to you you probably should use `getlnBoolean` instead.